# How to use autocomplete of richfaces with table layout?

Tags: java, eclipse, jsf, jboss, richfaces

I'm using `rich:autocomplete` for user search.

Search result contains all the details of user like name, address, age & photo.

This is my code:

```
<rich:autocomplete mode="client" showButton="true" 
        layout="table" autocompleteMethod="#{patientSearch.autocomplete}" 
        fetchValue="#{patient.patientId}" id="txtPatientSearch" var="patient">
    <rich:column>
        <h:graphicImage value="/resources/images/default.png" />
    </rich:column>
    <rich:column>
        <h:outputText value="#{patient.fname}" />
    </rich:column>
    <rich:column>
        <h:outputText value="#{patient.lname}" />
    </rich:column>
    <rich:column>
        <h:outputText value="#{patient.gender}" />
    </rich:column>
    <rich:column>
        <h:outputText value="#{patient.mrn}" />
    </rich:column>
</rich:autocomplete>
```

and the autocomplete method from the bean:

```
public List<SearchPatient> autocomplete(String search) {
    ArrayList<SearchPatient> result = new ArrayList<SearchPatient>();
    Iterator<SearchPatient> iterator 
        = patientDAO.searchPatientByAll(search, 1, this.sessionToken).iterator();
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        SearchPatient elem = ((SearchPatient) iterator.next());
        result.add(elem);
    }
    return result;
}
```

but when I deploy my app it gives exception:

> javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Property 'autocomplete' not found on type xtremum.health.web.bean.PatientSearchBean

this bean contains autocomplete method. How to use autocomplete for table structure?

Comment: Could you please post relevant code?

Comment: please format the code that is readable

Comment: i write the code properly but it wont show properly.. sory i cant do nothing its not my problem..

Comment: :) There are some tool if you have observed text editor properly, use them

Comment: but nw i just want answer of that question i hav not enough time to search abt editor tool

Comment: hey i edited the question while adding relevant code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello my problem is solved i make changes in my code and changes are

1. change mode from client to ajax,
2. autocompleteMethod & autocompleteList both are added in tag

Here is the XHTML

```
<rich:autocomplete mode="ajax" showButton="true"
    layout="table" autocompleteMethod="#{patientSearch.searchPatientByAll}"
    autocompleteList="#{patientSearch.searchPatient}"
    fetchValue="#{patient.patientId}" id="txtPatientSearch" var="patient">
  <rich:column>
    <h:graphicImage value="/resources/images/default.png" />
  </rich:column>
  <rich:column>
    <h:outputText value="#{patient.fname}" />
  </rich:column>
  <rich:column>
    <h:outputText value="#{patient.lname}" />
  </rich:column>
  <rich:column>
    <h:outputText value="#{patient.gender}" />
  </rich:column>
  <rich:column>
    <h:outputText value="#{patient.mrn}" />
  </rich:column>
</rich:autocomplete>
```

the bean method looks like

```
private @Getter @Setter List<SearchPatient> searchPatient;
public List<SearchPatient> searchPatientByAll(String search) {
  this.searchPatient=patientDAO.searchPatientByAll(search, 1, this.sessionToken);
  return this.searchPatient;
}
```